# How to update specific String from Specific line in file java

Tags: java, json, file

I have the following json file and i want to find the line by searching the id and change the size

```
{"BookDetails":[{"Suggested":"SoftwareEngnering","Size":"4MB","Title":"Introductionto softwareengnering","Author":" Tomas Jefferson ","page":1232,"Edition":"7th"}],"ID":"Lib@MU01"}

{"BookDetails":[{"Suggested":"Electrical Engnering","Size":"8MP","Title":"Electric And Life","Author":" Samson Stephen ","page":980,"Edition":"1th"}],"ID":"Lib@MU02"}
```

Comment: it is json file so i wnat to find the line by searching the id and change the size

Comment: Search for “java manipulate JSON”.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

Comment: `it is json file` a) you can find a tag that more precisely characterises your question than [tag:file]: [tag:json] b) you can *edit* your post - putting essential information like `find the line by searching the id and change the size` should *not* go in a comment. c) what *is* your [specific programming problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)? Figuring out the `ID` to find? Finding it in all those data sets? Manipulating `Size` in records found? Having the new value cause some specific effect?